After compiling the Python program into an .exe file, it failed to run
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options


def sign_in(url, username, password):
    edge_options = Options()
    edge_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)
    driver.get(url)

    username_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#_wifi_login > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > input[type=text]")
    password_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#_wifi_login > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > input[type=password]")
    login_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#_wifi_btn_login")

    username_input.send_keys(username)
    password_input.send_keys(password)
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.quit()


url_type = ("url")
username_type = "username"
password_type = "password"
sign_in(url_type, username_type, password_type)

The program is used to log into the campus network when there is no internet. It runs successfully when the code is still a .py file, but fails to run after compiling into an .exe file.
Versions:
selenium 4.1.1
Python 3.8.2
Edge 124.0.2478.51
Edge WebDriver 123.0.2420.97
(Clicked on Edge update by mistake, but Edge WebDriver has not been updated to version 2478 yet, and msedgedriver has not been added to the environment variables)
Also, when not using time.sleep(3), the program ends after entering the username and password without clicking the login button.
The computer is running on a Windows system.
When running the .exe file, a command prompt window flashes briefly and then closes. Can someone help me figure out what went wrong?

Run the .exe from a command prompt (rather than by double-clicking), so that you can see what was in that briefly shown window.  Hopefully that will give some hint as to the problem.
